# How to secure by Ajax calls from BOTs?

Tags: java, ajax

I am sure this is asked before but not able to find so am asking this again.

In my site i have a ajax call which saves the users email and some random site specific attribute. The request URL with attribute looks like this. This is a DB write request and gives a JSON reponse.

```
http://mysite.com/my-ajax-write-to-db?email=abc@xyz.com&siteattribute=XYZABCDEF
```

Now the problem i feel is that once this code gets live if some one/bot knows this URL, it can directly input lot of junks in my DB. What should i do to stop that? Any suggestion? Should i add some encryption mechanism?

Comment: first of all you could use POST method instead of GET. You could also create a robots.txt file to keep out bots like google etc.

Comment: Ya i can do POST but wont solve my issue. robots.txt will stop only good bots which are anyways not harmful. Thinking of stopping some one who intentionally written a bot to do this. Robot.txt wont help. Its upto the bot if they want to follow the robot.txt not the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

You could emulate the style used by Spring (or use Spring) - Each time your server loads the page, it issues a passkey in the form of a csrf token.  You can put this csrf token into your ajax request and validate it on the serverside.  I'm a Python programmer, so I'm not too familiar with Java servers, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290328/spring-3-1-mvc-spring-security-3-1-csrf-token) includes a link to presumably working code.

**EDIT**
If you don't use Spring, [DeveloperForce](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Cross_Site_Request_Forgery#Java) has listed 2 Java libraries which implement CSRF Tokens.  I automatically assumed Spring since Spring MVC is one of the most popular MVCs for Java.

As a general rule of thumb, pages which alter serverside data should usually be POST instead of GET since GET data will be recorded if someone bookmarks the URL or looks in browser history logs.

Comment: I am not working on Spring. I have to build it custom. But i think this is the right direction. Let me do some research on this.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX  set `“X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest”` header, which can then be used on the server side to detect if the call was made through an ajax call or from a bot.

I won't say it will stop 100% but will resist basic damage.

As of now I'm checking this in my MainFilter class  for detecting requests weather those are from BOt's or AJAX calls made by my pages only.

Let's hope we will get a sure shot solution.

Comment: Ya that's one way of doing it but as you said not a full proof way.Waiting for something more secured as db write is a costly operation specially when hosted on cloud

Comment: I could write a js script that sends his AJAX the same way his JS would, and that would come through as legit.

Answer (score 0):

Generalizing Snakes and Coffee's answer:

> You need to link the initial HTML request to the AJAX requests that are
>   made within its' javascript.

You do this by passing a GUID/ID with every AJAX call you make and check its validity server-side.

- As long as your backend serves HTML pages by rendering them from a
  back-end language (ASP/PHP/Django/etc), then you can easily embed a
  hidden tag with a GUID to the HTML as the server receives the initial HTML
  request, and store the GUID on the server.
- Once you've got a valid GUID on the server, you can be extra cautious
  by discarding it after a set time, set number of uses and/or identify if a single instance
  of the HTML page is sending too many/too quickly AJAX requests.

Remember that even using the GUID, as soon as the browser has it, a bot/malicious user could grab it and use it as a valid AJAX request.

As such, **the key security measure here is being able to scope an ajax's requests to a single HTML request and restricting use to it**.

Ask yourself questions like "Do I ever need to make this ajax request more than once per instance of this page?" - if not, then catch when it does happen on server-side and you'll know its malicious.