# How to enable CSRF protection in Spring Security 3.0

Tags: java, xml, spring-security, csrf, csrf-protection

I'm trying to enable CSRF protection in Spring Security 3.0. All the articles I've found point to using the `<csrf>` tag, which doesn't exist in this version of Spring Security and there's no chance of me upgrading to a newer version of Spring any time soon. (Corporate environment)

With this in mind, how can we implement CSRF protection?

We're using Spring 3, Java 8 and JBoss 5.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290328/spring-3-1-mvc-spring-security-3-1-csrf-token